# Checkbox 'checked' value inconsistently undefined

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a long table of items each with a checkbox. Onchange I call a function which merely alerts the checked value:

```
<input class="selectedCB" id="13" onchange="showInput(13);" type="checkbox">
<input class="selectedCB" id="14" onchange="showInput(14);" type="checkbox">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"><!--
  function showInput(idx) {
    alert($('#'+idx).prop('checked'));    
  }
//--></script>
```

In my page (full of other script and stuff) I get undefined from some and the correct value from others.
In a 'clean' test page they work perfectly.
I am unsure where to start looking for what else might be making some remain undefined when checked.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why use numbers as ID's...

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Unique DB content items - I don't concatenate to a string merely so that I don't later have to explode it again.

Comment: Check, if there is any error on console when you get the value 'undefined'.

Comment: Can you try `alert($('#'+idx).is(':checked'));    `

Comment: @ robert - there is only one function, and I'm not sure it would be any cleaner if I used Jquery to listen for the change event... maybe it would.  I'll give it a go.

Comment: @Pranav - no error in console.

Comment: @Arun - is(':checked') give me the wrong boolean value - even if not undefined.

Comment: @Lochinvar that means your selector `$('#'+idx)` might be wrong... check whether there any other element with the `id` the checkbox for which the test is failing

Comment: If checkbox with id `5` is failing then in your browser console test `$([id="5"]).length` and see the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `onchange` attribute like:

```
 onchange="showInput(this.checked);"
```

and the javascript like:

```
function showInput(ischecked) {
    alert(ischecked);
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/487pg/3/)

Comment: Thanks Palash - this worked (or at least a slight variation to pass the ID as well so that I know which associated elements to show / hide)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector and [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) filter method

```
<input class="selectedCB" id="13" onchange="showInput(13);" type="checkbox">
<input class="selectedCB" id="14" onchange="showInput(14);" type="checkbox">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"><!--
  function showInput(idx) {
    alert($('#'+idx).is(':checked'));    
  }
//--></script>
```

Comment: Hi Arun - for some reason this also kept giving me inconsistent / wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting `undefined` on some checkboxes, but not others, I would bet you have some typos when assigning handlers.

Try assigning your handler once for all checkboxes and see if that helps:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"].selectedCB').on('change', function(e) {
        alert($(this).prop('checked'));
    };
});
```

Comment: Yes, thanks - I gave this a go, but because of the sequence of ajax calls that loads the content, this way doesn't work in this instance.  Besides, the items are create by a server side php script, so typos 'should' be consistently wrong.